# What can be used for vue/cli frontend / Laravel 6 Backend REST API testing

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, vuejs2

I have expierence of using laravel dusk for testing laravel 5 app with using of vuejs 2 components 
Now I make @vue/cli 4.0.5 / vuex 3 app with data reading from Laravel 6 Backend REST API and 
wonder how both parts of the app can be tested?

Can laravel dusk be used for this or there are some better tools for this ?

Thanks!